# Using str_replace on Woocommerce checkout billing phone field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

In WooCommerce I would like to replace some characters in billing_phone field, using `str_replace()`.

I tried below code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'phone_replace' );
function phone_replace( $order_id ) {
    if (! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        str_replace( array('۱'), array('1'), $_POST['billing_phone'] );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Which is the correct hook for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `str_replace()` on the billing phone, the right hook is always the same:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'update_order_meta_billing_phone' );
function update_order_meta_billing_phone( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        // Check and update
        $billing_phone = str_replace( array('۱'), array('1'), $_POST['billing_phone'] );
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $phone_sabet ) );

        ## User data billing phone ##

        // Get the user ID
        $user_id = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_customer_user', true );
        // Get the billing phone user data
        $user_billing_phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', true );
        // Check and update
        if( ! empty ( $user_billing_phone ) ) {
            $user_billing_phone = str_replace( array('۱'), array('1'), $user_billing_phone );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $user_billing_phone );
        } else {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', $billing_phone );
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

Comment: This works well. I just used the default WP `get_current_user_id()` to get the `$user_id`